# Azure Blob Service REST API returns 403 error: "Request date header not specified"

Tags: azure

I try to use Blob Service REST API, List Containers (REST API):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179352.aspx

So I get access keys from Management Portal->Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN -> Storage Accounts, where I selected my storage (aziztest) and get keys from View Access Keys:
there are 2 keys Primary and Secondary.

Then using I created String to Sign:
GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Wed, 29 Feb 2012 06:05:13 GMT\nx-ms-version:2009-09-19\n/aziztest\ncomp:list

and make Authorization header using Primary Access Key of my storage:
Authorization: SharedKey aziztest:OjfrOTuO4zy1oUWGHkw8uj3%2BgAZq33GWe15gPT/PK%2Bk%3D

And then make GET request to:
http://aziztest.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list

But I get an error:
`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:892d1f31-a20d-45a5-b16a-2f7c07519863\nTime:2012-02-29T00:02:44.2841133ZRequest date header not specified

What is wrong in my procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done seems pretty good, I presume you're following the [instructions on MSDN on how to create the authentication header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx)?  I can see you've used them in the string which you are signing, but have you included `x-ms-date` and `x-ms-version` actually in your request header?  The error message would indicate you haven't.

Comment: OK, now I set header as: 'x-ms-version: 2009-09-19\nx-ms-date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 23:20:13 GMT\nAuthorization: SharedKey aziztest:TXhHOFdpTkVNZy83Z0xsaVVlci9sRkxxc2RYZFJ2R0l4L2ZFT2ZtUmxOaz0%3D\n'. But now I got an error: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code><Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.\nRequestId:ad4d0c0b-8664-49a8-adda-ce2c9d35d72b\nTime:2012-02-29T17:20:13.3766711Z</Message></Error>'

Comment: I would say that again the error message is telling you what to do.  Go back to the link I provided and make sure that you're following all of the steps to generate the authentication header.  Maybe you're not UTF-8 encodeing the items before you hash them?

Answer (score 1):

I hit similar errors when uploading a blob to azure storage container but coding in javascript. Posting the [link](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/03/21/putting-a-blob-in-azure-from-windows-store-app-in-javascript/) to code listing here. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I lost one day investigating error "The Date header in the request is incorrect" - and problem was in generating date via PHP. Correct date format is `date("D, d M Y H:i:s T");`

I used "j" for day, but f.e. Wed, 9 May 2018 10:20:30 GMT is incorrect, it has to be Wed, 09 May 2018 10:20:30 GMT.

Comment: The scourge of date formats is only getting worse. There's no clue what the purpose of this header is but anyway... make sure you zero pad your date. 9 Aug doesn't work, 09 Aug does. Now on to the next arcane error message

Answer (score 0):

Details on authentication procedures can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx

My guess is that x-ms-date is more than 15 minutes from the time the server gets the request.

Answer (score 0):

I the same problem in a php application and the issue was the filename encoding accents, so i ended up converting the name of the file to a base64 like this:

```
 $ext=explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $_FILES["file"]["name"]=str_replace("=","",base64_encode($_FILES["file"]["name"])).".".$ext[count($ext)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this via Logic apps the custom format for the Date header is:

`formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')` GMT